# How to prove that $\det\left[\pmatrix{u_1 & v_1\\ u_2 & v_2\\ u_3 & v_3}\pmatrix{s_1 & s_2 & s_3\\ t_1 & t_2 & t_3}\right]=0$?

Tags: determinant

> Evaluate $\det\left[\begin{pmatrix}
> u_1 & v_1\\ 
> u_2 & v_2\\ 
> u_3 & v_3
> \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> s_1 & s_2 & s_3\\ 
> t_1 & t_2 & t_3
> \end{pmatrix}\right]$.

I really don't want to expand the matrix product, is there simpler way?

Comment: Hi, please always include some English words in the title, so that the usual context menu on right-click is not overridden by MathJax menu.

Comment: I thought that would exceed the max word length..

Comment: In general, we have [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/480854/8271)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}u_1&v_1\\u_2&v_2\\u_3&v_3\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}s_1&s_2&s_3\\t_1&t_2&t_3\end{pmatrix}$, since $A$ is a $3\times 2$ matrix and $AB$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix it follows $\text{rank}(AB)\le\text{rank}(A)\le 2$, then $\det(AB)=0$.

Comment: And the same is true in general. If the product of two nonsquare matrices gives a square matrix it will never be invertible.

Comment: Learning little facts like this is why I go on mathSE.

Comment: @leo That's false, since you can find two vectors whose dot product is nonzero.

Comment: @Nishant you're right, let me correct myself: _Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ be a $n\times m$ matrix. If $n\lt m$ then $AB$ is not invertible._